# Contador de iteración y elemento bucle for python

Tags: python, bucle-for

estoy tratando de hacer el conteo de las palabras de una lista para ingresar un salto de linea en medio de ellas.

```
def salto_linea_nombre(nombre_empresa):
    """
    Separa el nombre y cuenta el numero de palabras para inserta un salto de linea en medio de ellas
    :param nombre_empresa:
    :return: salto_nombre
    """
    from math import floor

    separacion = nombre_empresa.split()
    pibote = int(floor(len(separacion)/2))
    salto_nombre = ""
    for palabra in separacion:
        salto_nombre = salto_nombre + " " + palabra
        if pibote ==
           salto_nombre = salto_nombre + "\n"

    return salto_nombre
```

necesito saber en que iteracion me encuentro para agregar el salto de linea en el lugar indicado, se que puedo agregar una variable  que se inicialice en 0 y que se incremente en cada iteracion. Pero tambien se que hay una forma "más python" usando dos variable en el for, pero no recuerdo bien como se usa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás describiendo es el built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), el cual recibe un iterable como argumento y genera tuplas de la forma `(contador, elemento)` empezando la cuenta desde cero en cada llamada a su método `__next__`:

```
def salto_linea_nombre(nombre_empresa):
    """
    Separa el nombre y cuenta el numero de palabras para inserta un salto de linea en medio de ellas
    :param nombre_empresa:
    :return: salto_nombre
    """

    separacion = nombre_empresa.split()
    pibote = len(separacion) // 2 - 1
    salto_nombre = ""
    for indice, palabra in enumerate(separacion):
        salto_nombre = salto_nombre + " " + palabra
        if pibote == indice:
           salto_nombre = salto_nombre + "\n"

    return salto_nombre

print(salto_linea_nombre("stack overflow en español"))
```

Ten en cuenta que la función anterior crea un espacio antes de la primera palabra y otro después del salto de linea, que posiblemente no quieras.

Puedes usar una combinación de `str.join` y rebanado de listas para conseguir lo que quieres de forma más directa y sin los susodichos espacios:

```
def salto_linea_nombre(nombre_empresa):
    """
    Separa el nombre y cuenta el numero de palabras para inserta un salto de linea en medio de ellas
    :param nombre_empresa:
    :return: salto_nombre
    """

    separacion = nombre_empresa.split()
    pibote = len(separacion) // 2
    salto_nombre = f'{" ".join(separacion[:pibote])}\n{" ".join(separacion[pibote:])}'
    return salto_nombre

print(salto_linea_nombre("stack overflow en español"))
```

Observa que he eliminado `math.floor`, dado que siempre lo aplicas a un número positivo, puedes simplemente truncar, en este caso aplicando la división entera (`//`).

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió mucho la información que me diste, como era para agregarlo en un pdf lo que hice fue almacenar cada join en una lista y luego posicionar el segundo debajo del primero porque no tomo el \n